# Xcode 7.2 - Creating New Project '' TVOS '' Missing

Tags: xcode, xcode7.2, tvos9.1

Just updated `xcode 7.2` on macbook pro when I'm creating new project there is "TVOS" missing.

Do I have to reinstall xcode or something I'm missing???

Please find the following screenshot for the reference.

[image: My XCode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall it.... It will solve your problem i had same issue .

- Step 1: Delete the application from the applications folder
- Step 2: Go to the Library folder and delete the folder named Xcode
- Step 3: Go to the Developer folder and delete the Xcode folder
- Step 4: Reinstall.

You are done!